# Appending to an entry in mysql table to prevent duplicate entry

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this :

```
a   1
b   2
a   3
```

I want to append 3 to 1. The result should be as follows

```
a   1,3
b   2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example of group_concate I have showned here

INSERTION CODE

```
INSERT INTO tblname ('id',...) 
SELECT field_name AS `id` GROUP_CONCAT(`column_name` separator ',') AS Column FROM mytbl group by id, `column_name`
```

SELECTTION CODE

```
select id, group_concat(`column_name` separator ',') as `Column`
from
(
  select id, concat(`column_name`, ':',
  group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `Name`
  from mytbl
  group by id, `column_name`
) tbl
group by id;
```

Comment: Sorry I need the insertion code , not the selection code

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

```
select id, group_concat(`Name` separator ',') as `Column`
from
(
select id,
group_concat(`Value` separator ',') as `Name`
from mytbl
group by id
) tbl
group by id;
```

here column is your array column(2nd column) and id is your integer value(1st column).